# Перебор значений в регулярке php

Tags: php

Есть поиск значений в строке:

```
 //Материал
    $material = "Стальная балка";

    // Алюминий
    if (preg_match('/.*(алюмин).*/iu', $material)) {
      $material_result = "alum";
    }
    // Сталь
    if (preg_match('/.*(сталь).*/iu', $material)) {
      $material_result = "steel";
    }
    //Дерево
    if (preg_match('/.*(дерев).*/iu', $material)) {
      $material_result = "wood";
    }

echo $material_result;
```

Выдает нужное значение, если то встречается в строке (в данном случае передаст значение steel). Но, если ни одного из значений не находится, то выдается ошибка. Не могу сообразить, как добавить условие "если ничего не найдено, не выводить ничего", или фразу "нет результата" в echo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто добавить дефолтное значения, перед ифами.

```
//Материал
    $material = "Стальная балка";
    $material_result = 'нет результата'
    // Алюминий
    if (preg_match('/.*(алюмин).*/iu', $material)) {
      $material_result = "alum";
    }
    // Сталь
    if (preg_match('/.*(сталь).*/iu', $material)) {
      $material_result = "steel";
    }
    //Дерево
    if (preg_match('/.*(дерев).*/iu', $material)) {
      $material_result = "wood";
    }

echo $material_result;
```

Comment: как просто и работает) спасибо!